# Renaming collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to rename a collection in MongoDB. I accidently wrote

`db.currentName.renameCollection()`

but I should have wrote

`db.currentName.renameCollection(newName)`

Now when I try to rename the collection I get "source namespace does not exist, code 26". How can I rename it?

Comment: The command `db.currentName.renameCollection()` without any argument returns with an error. It doesn't affect anything.

Comment: It didn't return an error for me. It came back with this: "{ "ok" : 1 }". Similarly, I called a collection "1" and it did it. Then when I tried to do something with that collection I got errors. I then realised that collection names must start with letters or an underscore. So then I tried to delete it but I couldn't select it because it can't recognise a number as a collection name. Now it's just floating around on my database server. It SHOULD be giving me an error in the first instance.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you working with? What operating system? What tool are you using to access MongoDB?

Comment: I'm using windows 32 bit for development so I've had to use an older version, 3.2.22